# google cloud sql PostgreSQL 9.6 ST_GeomFromGeoJSON JSON-C Error

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, google-cloud-sql

I am using Google Cloud Sql service, PostgreSQL 9.6 beta. When trying to insert polygon data into polygon column getting following error:

"You need JSON-C for ST_GeomFromGeoJSON"

In Table column data type is following:

" polygon geometry NOT NULL, "

Any suggestion ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Rather old question but still may save somebody some time. Until this writing, JSON-C support is missing in Postgresql/POSTGIS in google's cloud sql. There is an open issue tracker.

[(Bug) Postgresql PostGIS missing JSON-C support.](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37302950)